# Usage of Azure App Configuration's Feature Flags in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, featuretoggle, azure-app-configuration

I'm working on exploring the following 2 features of Azure App Configuration in Azure Function's Http Trigger

1. Externalizing the App Settings
2. Feature Flags

Below is how i'm getting the reference of the configuration

[image]

So, when I use _configuration["SomeAppSettingKey"], I'm able to retrieve the value. So, I'm able to achieve #1 feature mentioned above.

My Question is, How do we retrieve the Feature Flag information? I have tried the below ways.

[image]

I would appreciate if someone could help me in understanding how to retrieve it in Azure Functions (I'm using V3)? A Sample code or any reference to documentation would be helpful.

Thanks.

Update1:
I can deserialize the json content as shown below. But, is this is the right approach?

[image]

Where FeatureManager is a class that I have defined as shown below.

[image]

Comment: are you saying _configuration["appconfig.featureflag/TurnOnGreeting"] is not working?

Comment: It returns me a json. But, Is that the best way to access the Feature flags?

Comment: i'm able to de-serialize the json content. I have updated the same in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all you need is to call `UseFeatureFlags()` function as part of `AddAzureAppConfiguration` to let the App Configuration provider know you want to use feature flags. An example can be found following the link below. It uses the `FunctionsStartup` and dependency injection (DI) of Azure Functions. An instance of a feature manager is put into the DI.

https://github.com/Azure/AppConfiguration/blob/master/examples/DotNetCore/AzureFunction/FunctionApp/Startup.cs

The link below shows how you can obtain the instance of `IFeatureManagerSnapshot` from DI and use it as part of your Azure Functions call.

https://github.com/Azure/AppConfiguration/blob/master/examples/DotNetCore/AzureFunction/FunctionApp/ShowBetaFeature.cs

Answer (score 0):

Deserialize JSON is not a good idea, every time you will add new key you need to modify your class.

```
private static IConfiguration Configuration { set; get; }

static Function1()
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString"));
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string keyName = "TestApp:Settings:Message";
    string message = Configuration[keyName];

    return message != null
        ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(message)
        : new BadRequestObjectResult($"Please create a key-value with the key '{keyName}' in App Configuration.");
}
```

Comment: The question is on how to retrieve the Feature Flag settings not the regular Key-Value pair.

Comment: Ohh.. You're looking this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-feature-flags-dotnet-core

Comment: the link that you have shared is for ASP.NEt core. I'm looking something similar for Azure Functions

Comment: I think we can use UseFeatureFlags() middleware in Azurefucntion startup class